# splash screen with loading indicator using storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm working on an app for a blog site, and I'm trying to keep the Default.png launch image up with a spinning indicator while I load the initial headlines into the tableview.

I set up a viewcontroller/view in my storyboard with the launch image and indicator.

I then have the following in the viewDidLoad: method of my navigationController's rootview

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SplashLoader"] animated:NO];
```

And once the headlines are loaded I use:

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Am I way off base here? Or is this the right way to be doing this?

I've seen people doing something like this in app delegate, but that was before storyboards... If I'm supposed to be doing this in the app delegate then how do I instantiate the view controller out of the storyboard?

Thanks,

Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've done it is to make a UIImageView using the Default.png image. In viewWillAppear: I add it to the view controller's view property. In viewDidAppear: I use a UIView animation to fade out the image view by setting its alpha to 0. Upon completion of the animation, viewDidAppear: removes the image view from its superview and releases it (sets it to nil).

You have to keep a record of how many time viewWillAppear: and viewDidAppear: have been called because you only want this animation to happen when the app launches. Also, you have to think about which image to use to create the image view. If this is an iPhone app, you want to use Default.png. If it's an iPad app, you want to use Default-Portrait~ipad.png or Default-Landscape~ipad.png, depending on the orientation of the device when the app launches.

I'm not sure how you would accomplish the same effect in the app delegate. That seems like an unnecessarily complicated approach to me.